# Finding downloadable content in webpage without knowing what the page looks like

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I want to find downloadable content in a webpage but I don't know what the webpage looks like. Right now, I am looking at all links

```py
links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@href]")
```

and buttons

```py
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "button")
```

For each link (which has an `href` attribute as seen in the XPATH specification), I check whether or not it points to a page with some form of machine readable file I am looking for (either `.csv` or `.json`);  if the link does not have one of these extensions as a suffix, I assume it does not reference a machine readable file.

As for the buttons, I know of no way to check what they may contain other than naively clicking on them (`button.click()`). While this is clearly dangerous, especially because this function will be applied on thousands of websites, I don't know how else to do it.

Is there any other way I could check for downloadable content? Additionally, are there any other page elements I should be looking for, besides links and buttons, and are there any more efficient methods of doing what I want?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!